# Are the trees in randomForest dependent on each other?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I'm trying to understand the concept behind RandomForest. I came across an article https://towardsdatascience.com/enchanted-random-forest-b08d418cb411 which says "*We repeatedly select data from the data set (with replacement) and build a Decision Tree with each new sample*".

I would like to know if the Decision Trees built have any dependencies on each other ?

Answer (score 4):

No, they are not.

In Random Forest (and bootstrap aggregation in general), individual decision trees are connected only in the sense that their training samples partially overlap. After their training datasets are sampled, they learn independently.

There is, though, another framework, *gradient boosting*, where each tree depends on all the trees built before it.

Comment: Correct, and that's why RF is straightforward to parallelize, in contrast with gradient boosted trees...